# Conditional proxy pass instead of redirect

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

Need to "redirect" conditional url to anothre domain with request parameter and request body in GET/POST. This is how it works now.

```
   location ~* /aa/.*/bb.json{
                 proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:7001;
                 if ($arg_bornEnv = pro ) { rewrite ^.*$ http://pro.xxxx.com$uri last;}
                 if ($arg_bornEnv = pre ) { rewrite ^.*$ http://pre.xxxx$uri last;}
             }
```

It works in browser and will redirect url to destination with a "302" code. It means it will changed url in url field. I want to accomplish this throw code in one request, for example, httpclient etc.

Can this be done with a conditional proxy pass?

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~* /aa/.*/bb.json{
   if ($arg_bornEnv = pro ) { rewrite ^.*$ http://pro.xxxx/$1 redirect;}
   if ($arg_bornEnv = pre ) { rewrite ^.*$ http://pre.xxxx/$1 redirect;}
   proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:7001;
}
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit?

Comment: for sure,  How you need change the DOMAIN, so you need execute a redirect and not an internal rewrite. You also need to keep the URI and Parameters, so You can repass it in $1 captured in Regex ^.*$. And after the rules you can send to the backend by proxy_pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~* /aa/.*/bb.json {
             if ($arg_bornEnv = pro ) { proxy_pass http://pro.xxxx;}
             if ($arg_bornEnv = pre ) { proxy_pass http://pre.xxxx;}

             proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:7001;
         }
```

This is how it works now.